Tourist Visa in South Korea
I have an important question related to my Visa Status. I travelled to Korea frequently on a Tourist Visa, since I used to work there for years and now I have close relations there. I work online as a Tutor in my home country (Austria), therefore I can afford my trips. This time I came back to apply for a student visa, but entered Korea with a Tourist Visa again. Immigration stopped me and asked me for a return ticket. I booked a flight in December (1week before my tourist visa expires), but they told me I have to book a flight in 2 weeks, which I did and showed them. They did not really understand my situation.
Now I have 2 flights back, and on my Visa Stamp in my passport it says I am allowed to stay 3 months, not 2 weeks only.
Is it correct that I am legally allowed to stay 3 months if it says on my Visa Stamp? Or is it different in the system?
Since I am trying to apply for a student visa, those 3 months could be granted, since I heard other countries like US, UK never had an issue like this.
Thank you in advance!

How long do you plan to study for? Many countries don't allow you to switch to a student visa in-country. You're supposed to apply from your country of residence. If you've been spending a lot of time in Korea, immigration may suspect you're living there/making a life there. Are you working while there?

Thanks for the reply!!At least a year and apply for jobs in the meantime. It is possible to change from a tourist visa to a student visa in korea. My issue is that I am currently on a tourist visa and I don’t know when I have to leave, since it will take some time to apply for a student visa. If my stamp on the passport says 90 days, it should be 90 days I’m legally able to stay right? Or just 2 weeks?
